# How to remove a space after a specific word in R

Tags: r

For example, if the word is `happy`, then:

Input: `"The Bunny is happy to be alive, the Rabbit is happy too"`

Output: `"The Bunny is happyto be alive, the Rabbit is happytoo"`

Thank you

Comment: `gsub("happy *", "happy", input)`

Comment: Thank you so much. Any chance you also know how to do that on Python?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid not!

Comment: Thanks anyway. For future generations: input.replace("happy ", "happy")

Answer (score 1):

Use following regex

```
(?<=happy)\\s
```

in the comment of your question, you are replacing **word**+**whitesace** on **word**. But in approach placed above, you are removoing **only** whitespace.